# 'Freeze' google sheets column value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I use to keep track of my spending. I create a new 'block' of data every time I get paid, and I have formulas in some of the cells that calculate balances.

I have data that goes back over a year, that I'm no longer interested in calculating any more. Once Google Sheets loads my page, is there an easy way to change the value in a cell to the value that is actually there, as opposed to the formula? That way, it doesn't take my page so long to load calculating values that aren't going to be changing any more?

Comment: did you try to hide them?

Comment: I can hide the rows, but I believe the formulas in the columns still get executed? it wouldn't be a big deal if they were local function calls, like floor, ceiling, etc, but they are calling my external scripts

Comment: depends on formulas. there are some that can skip hidden rows

Comment: are you saying that I can express that within the javascript function?

Comment: I didnt said that but you can try if you know how. I was referring to regular in cell formulas

Comment: @user1154644 Although I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct, if you want to put only the value by removing the formula from the cells with the formula, how about using Google Apps Script? I think that there are several workarounds for your situation. For example, in the simple case, you can use 2 lines script like ``var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange(); range.setValues(range.getValues());``. Of course, the script for all sheets can be also created. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.